# Angular Firestore - problem with async requests?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an issue with some basic logic. I have a User data structure with team field and other (uid email etc). Also, I have a team data structure with name, description, and an array of users in my firestore.

What I'm trying to do is to at the init of the app get the user team id from the user, then get the team and then get the team members user profiles. I've written the following code:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.userRef.valueChanges().pipe(map( (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.teamRef = this.afs.doc<Team>(`teams/${data.teams[0]}`);
      console.log(this.teamRef);
      console.log('init');
      this.getTeam();
    }));
  }

  private getTeam(): void {
    this.teamRef.valueChanges().pipe(map( (teamData: Team) => {
      this.team = teamData;
      console.log('team');
     this.getMembers();
    }));
  }

  private getMembers(): void {
    console.log('members init');
    this.team.members.forEach((value) => {
      this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${value}`).valueChanges().pipe(map( (data: User) => {
        this.teamMembers.push(data);
      }));
    });
    console.log('members:');
    console.log(this.teamMembers);
  }
```

My User interface looks like so:

```
export interface User {
  email: string;
  uid: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  teams?: string[]; // acutally only 1 team - field contains team doc id
}
```

Any my Team interface:

```
export interface Team {
  name: string;
  description?: string;
  admin?: string; // = creator - first user
  members?: string[]; // array of users UIDs.
  boards?: string[]; // array of board docs id.
}
```

the data in the firesotre database are correct...

I don't know what am I doing wrong. I don't get any data, even if the actions are invoked on the onInit hook

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the observables, so that they start running.`valueChanges()` returns an observable, so you need to subscribe to listen to those changes. your code code should look like this. You need to for all the valueChanges() related operations.

```
 this.userRef.valueChanges().pipe(map( (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.teamRef = this.afs.doc<Team>('teams/${data.teams[0]}');
      console.log(this.teamRef);
      console.log('init');
      this.getTeam();
    })).subscribe();
```

Comment: thats weird because in other component I'm using same logic and it works. I have the following somewhere else: 
  `this.userRef.valueChanges().pipe(map( (data: User) => {
      this.userTeams = data.teams;
    }));`

Comment: I am pretty much sure, you need to subscribe to observables as they are cold by default. check this (example)[https://alligator.io/angular/cloud-firestore-angularfire/]. Can you put your demo in stackblitz, It wiil be easy.